# How to compute the measurement probability in swap test?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, textbook-and-exercises, quantum-circuit

The figure of a circuit and the state are as follows.

The final state before the measurement is $|O_{out}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle+|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle)+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle-|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle)$.

Measuring the first qubit of this state produces outcome 1, how can I get the probability $\frac12(1-|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2)$?

[image: figure of a circuit]

[image: the description of the state]

Answer (score 6):

It's a fantastic question because the typical measurement intuition we apply no longer is sufficient - it's really necessary to formalize measurement.

Specifically, we create a set of nonlinear operators $M_\psi = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$, where the probability of measuring $\psi$ on an arbitrary state $|\phi\rangle $ is $\langle \phi | M^\dagger M | \phi \rangle$.

In our case, we have a measurement operator $M_1$ we are interested in. However, we can actually apply $M_0$ for simplicity, and then subtract this probability from 1. Thus, where $| \varphi \rangle $ is the state provided above:

\begin{align}
   \langle \varphi | M^\dagger M | \varphi \rangle &= \langle \varphi |0\rangle \langle 0| 0\rangle \langle 0|\varphi\rangle \\
&= \langle \varphi|0\rangle\langle 0|\varphi\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{4} (\langle \phi|\langle \psi| + \langle \psi|\langle \phi|)( |\phi \rangle |\psi \rangle + |\psi \rangle |\phi \rangle) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(2 \langle\phi| \langle\psi|\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle + 2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Big(|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2 + 1 \Big)
\end{align}

Thus, because this is the zero probability, we have:

$$
   1 - \frac{1}{2}\Big(|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2 + 1 \Big) = \frac{1 - |\langle \psi|\phi \rangle|^2}{2} = \frac{1 - |\langle \phi|\psi \rangle|^2}{2}
$$

As desired.

Comment: Thank you, can you specify how can get the result $|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2$ from $2 \langle\phi| \langle\psi|\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle$? That's what I'm confused.

Comment: $ \langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \psi \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi \rangle (\langle \phi | \psi \rangle)^*= |\langle \phi | \psi \rangle|^2 $

Comment: That's the point. $ \langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \psi \rangle $ just because $ \langle \phi | \langle \psi | $ are in two separate direct product space?

Comment: $\langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \psi \rangle$ because $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle$ is just a number and so it can be moved in front of $\langle \phi |$

Comment: After my checking calculation, I found that the results of $\langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \langle \psi |\phi \rangle \langle \phi | \psi \rangle$ and $\langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \langle\phi|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ are different, while the calculation result $\langle \phi | \langle \psi | \phi \rangle |\psi \rangle =\langle\phi|\otimes\langle\psi|\cdot|\phi\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle= \langle\phi|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$ seems to be right.

Comment: @KarryMa notationally, we work inside out - $\psi, \phi$ should associate together, your second equation is wrong on the second step. I recommend that you try to do the equation with vectors more generally, because it seems like bra-ket is what's confusing you

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're happy with the idea that the state before measurement is
$$|O_{out}\rangle=\frac12|0\rangle(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle+|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle)+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle-|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle).$$
Now you want to measure qubit 1 in the 0/1 basis. There's a couple of different ways you might approach this.

1. Define the two measurement projectors to be $P_0=|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I\otimes I$ (i.e. measure first qubit in 0, and do nothing to the other two), and $P_1=|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I\otimes I$. The probability of getting the 0 answer is $\langle O_{out}|P_0|O_{out}\rangle$.
2. Alternative, rewrite your state as
   $$
   |O_{out}\rangle=\gamma_0|0\rangle|\sigma\rangle+\gamma_1|1\rangle|\tau\rangle,
   $$
   where $|\sigma\rangle$ and $|\tau\rangle$ are properly normalised vectors, and the coefficients $\gamma_{0/1}$ compensate for that normalisation. The probability of getting the answer 0 when you measure the first qubit is $|\gamma_0|^2$. So, we have
   $$
   \gamma_0|\sigma\rangle=\frac12(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle+|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle).
   $$
   Take the inner product of that equation with itself and you get
   \begin{align*}
   |\gamma_0|^2&=\frac14(\langle\phi |\langle\psi |+\langle\psi |\langle\phi|)(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle+|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle) \\
   &=\frac14(2+2|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2).
   \end{align*}
   The actual question requires the probability of getting answer 1. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Nice answer, but the question requires to obtain the expression for $|\gamma_1|^2$, not for $|\gamma_0|^2$.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan Since this could easily be a homework question, the actual calculation is left for the reader (or let's pretend that's what I inteneded ;) )